# apache poi read custom property

Tags: apache-poi, custom-properties

I have added a custom property to my workbook object like:

```
((XSSFWorkbook)workBook).getProperties().getCustomProperties().addProperty("fileNameSuffix" , "testName");
```

Now how can I read it back again.

Why there is no such method as `getProperty(String key)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure a way to do it, but I do not really like it this way

```
    List<CTProperty> customProperties = workBook.getProperties().getCustomProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPropertyList();
    String fileNameSuffix = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < customProperties.size() ; i++) {
        CTProperty property = customProperties.get(i);
        if (customProperties.get(i).getName().equals("testName"))
            fileNameSuffix = property.getLpwstr(); // getLpwstr() will return the value of the property
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean like the method [POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties.getProperty(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.CustomProperties.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)? I think that should do what you want. Well, assuming you're on a new enough version of Apache POI to have it at least!

However, do note that it returns a CTProperty object, which is fairly low-level, and doesn't have an explicit type on it. You'll have to call the various `isSetXXX` methods to work out what kind it is, then `getXXX` to get the value.

There's an example of how to do that in [POIXMLPropertiesTextExtractor](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ooxml/extractor/POIXMLPropertiesTextExtractor.java)